# Replace a button that loads a prompt by its result

Tags: javascript, button, text, prompt

I have a text. Inside, I want to ask the reader questions where answers will be inserted inside the text. And I want the questions to be prompted by a button and have the button disappear when the prompt is validated.

So what I have for now is this:

```
Once upon a time in <button onclick="prompt('Where do you live?')">Where do you live?</button>, a very beautiful place…
```

It gets me the button inside my text, the prompt I want, but how do I get the result of this prompt to replace the button when I close the prompt after clicking OK?

Answer (score 3):

This `onclick()` does what I think you want.

```html
Once upon a time in <button onclick="this.outerText = prompt('Where do you live?');">Where do you live?</button>, a very beautiful place…
```

Basically, it sets the value of the prompt to the `outerText` of the button.  `outerText` replaces the entire button, while `innerText` would place it inside the button, if you want that instead.  It would look like this:

```html
Once upon a time in <button onclick="this.innerText = prompt('Where do you live?');">Where do you live?</button>, a very beautiful place…
```

Comment: It's worth noting that that is vulnerable to JavaScript injection.

Comment: What do you mean, @JackieChiles?

Comment: Thx a lot, the outerHTML is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Godisgood Run your code snippet with something like `<img src='https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png' onload='alert("Insert malicious code here");' />` entered into the prompt and you'll see what I mean. An attacker could replace the innocuous `alert` code with a malicious script. If that input is saved to the server and loaded by another user, data could potentially be stolen from the second user, for example. That's one reason Stack Snippets [run in a separate domain](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269753/830125).

Comment: @JackieChiles, I now see what you mean.  I replace "HTML" with "Text".  Is that better?  They can't put anything malicous now, can they?

Comment: @Godisgood: That should be better. If you were in a situation where you couldn't use that option, you could sanitize the input yourself using [character entities](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref).